# Организация Базы данных для сотрудника

Tags: база-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста как организовать структуру таблиц.
Есть карточка сотрудника, у сотрудника есть должность, и она принадлежит какому-то подразделению. Как правильно организовать структуру?
Должно быть так?

```
**Карточка сотрудника**
Код сотрудника
Фамилия 
Имя
Отчество
Пол
Код должности
Код Подразделение
```

Или необходимо в карточке оставить подразделение? И связать уже подразделение и должность между собой?

Comment: Скорее в карточке оставить только должность. И сделать таблицу должностей, где у должности будет указано подразделение. Это если первое предложение в вопросе верно и должность строго привязана к одному подразделению

Comment: а если не строго привязано? Например, может быть что в двух отделах могут работать Ведущие специалисты, или может быть Начальник отдела

Comment: Тогда вы вопрос задали не корректно. "_у сотрудника есть должность и она принадлежит какому то подразделению_" по моему можно понять только как жесткую связку. А если это не так, то вообще нет смысла говорить о связи должности с подразделением и тогда у сотрудника есть и то и другое, как вы и указали.

Comment: Т.е. Верно будит если я оставлю так как есть? Что бы код подразделения и код должности был в таблице Карточка сотрудника?

Comment: да. в конце концов сотрудник же может менять должность без смены подразделения и переходить в другое подразделение не меняя должность

Comment: Спасибо, Вам большое.